# Login to different active directories programaticly in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, membership-provider

The company that I work for has two active directories (**ad1.com**, **ad2.com**) because it has two different stores that had nothing to do with each other and plenty of users but now the managers of both stores need a page in common.
So I need to create a login where the users could access using just their Active Directory username and password.

In the login page there should be a list to choose the active directory and after that the user **Paul**(paul@**ad1**.com) and the user **Paul**(paul@**ad2**.com) with their respective password should be able to access to the page.

I have the code needed for the logIn page for one AD and works great but I don't know if it's possible to make the page available for two ADs.
Do I need some extra configuration on the server?

I google this but didn't find anything related.

Comment: AD trust relationship?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and cheaper) just to combine the active directories and separate their domains within active directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the code required for one AD, you could very well use the same code with slight modifications to authenticate against another AD.

Based on the domain name, you can identify the settings for AD and perform your authentication.

In cases where you use two AD, only identifying the domain name matters E.g. 
ad1\username or username@ad1.com. You will not be able to achieve a login without the user specifying the domain name.

Comment: As I was able to login without the domain for the first I AD developed I thought that it was gonna be the same for the other one, now for the first I don't need to specify it but on the other hand for the second AD is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [LDAP Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and just definining it differently based on the dropdown list?

Something like:

```
string adPath = string.Empty;
string domainName = string.Empty;
switch (ddlOption.ToString()) 
    {
         case "ad1":
           adPath = "ad1Path";
           domainName = "ad1";
           break;
        case "ad2":
           adPath = "ad2Path";
           domainName = "ad2";
           break;
    }
LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
if (adAuth.IsAuthenticated(domainName, username, password))
{
    //redirect Logic
}
```